# No error message explaining why can't connect to server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, capistrano

I'm following along with a screencasthttp://railscasts.com/episodes/335-deploying-to-a-vps?view=asciicastthat that instructs how to deploy to a VPS with nginx and unicorn (I'm installing a Ruby on Rails app on ubuntu). After installing the various services (nginx, postgres, unicorn, ruby) and running `cap deploy:cold`, my app (as expected) displayed the default nginx page, which the screencast instructs to remove in the following way so that nginx serves the production app

```
deployer@li349-144:~$ sudo rm /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default 
[sudo] password for deployer: 
deployer@li349-144:~$ sudo service nginx restart
Restarting nginx: nginx.
```

I've previously deployed applications where, after removing this default page, the intended application appears.  However, after I run these commands on my server this time and navigate to the ip address, the browser tells me it can't connect to the server.  Not sure what was wrong, I tried to restart nginx, unicorn and postgres (all of which restarted successfully) but I got the same error message in the browser.

There's a log directory on my cloud server with a `unicorn.log` logfile and a `production.log` but neither of them indicate any problems. For example, the production.log only indicates that database migrations have been run, and this is the unicorn.log

```
I, [2013-07-11T23:26:57.717019 #6664]  INFO -- : listening on addr=/tmp/unicorn.qbruby3.sock fd=10
I, [2013-07-11T23:26:57.717480 #6664]  INFO -- : worker=0 spawning...
I, [2013-07-11T23:26:57.718428 #6664]  INFO -- : worker=1 spawning...
I, [2013-07-11T23:26:57.719538 #6667]  INFO -- : worker=0 spawned pid=6667
I, [2013-07-11T23:26:57.719713 #6667]  INFO -- : Refreshing Gem list
I, [2013-07-11T23:26:57.722070 #6664]  INFO -- : master process ready
I, [2013-07-11T23:26:57.726747 #6670]  INFO -- : worker=1 spawned pid=6670
I, [2013-07-11T23:26:57.727030 #6670]  INFO -- : Refreshing Gem list
I, [2013-07-11T23:27:09.930162 #6670]  INFO -- : worker=1 ready
I, [2013-07-11T23:27:10.084362 #6667]  INFO -- : worker=0 ready
I, [2013-07-12T01:05:52.638290 #6664]  INFO -- : reloading config_file=/home/michael/apps/qbruby3/shared/config/unicorn.rb
I, [2013-07-12T01:05:52.668897 #6664]  INFO -- : done reloading config_file=/home/michael/apps/qbruby3/shared/config/unicorn.rb
I, [2013-07-12T01:05:52.858858 #6664]  INFO -- : reaped #<Process::Status: pid 6667 exit 0> worker=0
I, [2013-07-12T01:05:52.859032 #6664]  INFO -- : worker=0 spawning...
I, [2013-07-12T01:05:52.860609 #7212]  INFO -- : worker=0 spawned pid=7212
I, [2013-07-12T01:05:52.860839 #7212]  INFO -- : Refreshing Gem list
I, [2013-07-12T01:05:52.875751 #6664]  INFO -- : reaped #<Process::Status: pid 6670 exit 0> worker=1
I, [2013-07-12T01:05:52.875944 #6664]  INFO -- : worker=1 spawning...
I, [2013-07-12T01:05:52.877405 #7215]  INFO -- : worker=1 spawned pid=7215
I, [2013-07-12T01:05:52.877651 #7215]  INFO -- : Refreshing Gem list
I, [2013-07-12T01:06:02.191290 #7212]  INFO -- : worker=0 ready
I, [2013-07-12T01:06:02.269397 #7215]  INFO -- : worker=1 ready
```

In this situation, what else could I check to identify the reason the app is not appearing?

Comment: Double check that you followed all previous instructions. Either server is not up or it's pointing to a wrong dir.

Comment: Can you ping the IP from your machine?

Comment: @Vimsha I did `ping 192.xxx.xxx.xxx` from the terminal and it kept responding `Request timeout for icmp_seq 0` etc

Comment: So that the problem. The mcahine you deployed to is not accessible from your machine. I don't think there is any problem with your installation